# R: Replace string with consecutive 0 less then three with 1

Tags: r

I have a  vector like this in R:

```
dt = data.frame(input=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1) )

dt
      input 
 # 1    0     
 # 2    0     
 # 3    1     
 # 4    1     
 # 5    0     
 # 6    0     
 # 7    1     
 # 8    0     
 # 9    0     
 # 10   0  
 # 11   1     
 # 12   1     
 # 13   1     
 # 14   0     
 # 15   1
```

I want to replace the consecutive 0, in which the length is less than three, with 1, and save it to a new column.

#update:
I also hope that the replacement only happens when less than three 0 are sandwiched between 1. So in this condition, I will ignore the two 0 in raw 1 and 2. (or also when happening in the tail or meet NA)

For example, I want to output:

```
      input output
 # 1    0     0
 # 2    0     0
 # 3    1     1
 # 4    1     1
 # 5    0     1
 # 6    0     1
 # 7    1     1
 # 8    0     0
 # 9    0     0
 # 10   0     0
 # 11   1     1
 # 12   1     1
 # 13   1     1
 # 14   0     1
 # 15   1     1
```

How can I write it in the foreach loop? (I have the data with thousands of rows)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a grouping column with `rleid` on the 'input' column, and `if` the number of rows is less than 3 and `all` values are 0, replace with 1 or else return input

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dt %>%
    mutate(new = cumsum(input)) %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(input)) %>%
    mutate(output = if(n() <3 & all(input == 0) & all(new > 0)) 1 else input) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp, -new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   input output
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     0      0
 2     0      0
 3     1      1
 4     1      1
 5     1      1
 6     0      1
 7     1      1
 8     0      0
 9     0      0
10     0      0
11     1      1
12     1      1
13     1      1
14     0      1
15     1      1
```

---

Or use `base R` with `rle`

```
dt$output <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(dt$input), 
     values[!values & lengths < 3 & seq_along(values) != 1] <- 1))
dt$output
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @akrun: why are row one and two not 1 in the output column as the sequence of zeros is < 3? many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update after clarification:**

We could now `ungroup()` and check if the sequence is wrapped by a `1` with `lag(input==1)`:

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(
    x= cumsum(input != lag(input, def = first(input)))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(x = seq_along(input),
         x = last(x)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(output = case_when(input == 0 & 
                              lag(input==1) &
                              x<=2 ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ as.numeric(input))) %>% 
  select(-x)
```

Output:

```
 A tibble: 15 x 2
   input output
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     0      0
 2     0      0
 3     1      1
 4     1      1
 5     1      1
 6     0      1
 7     1      1
 8     0      0
 9     0      0
10     0      0
11     1      1
12     1      1
13     1      1
14     0      1
15     1      1
```

**First answer:**

Here is a suggestion. But I don't understand the rows 1 and 2 in your output. "replace consecutive 0, in which the length is less than three, with 1" this is the case for row 1 and 2.

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(
    x= cumsum(input != lag(input, def = first(input)))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(x = seq_along(input),
         x = last(x)) %>% 
  mutate(output = case_when(input == 0 & x<=2 ~ 1,
                            TRUE ~ as.numeric(input))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-x)
```

```
   input output
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     0      1
 2     0      1
 3     1      1
 4     1      1
 5     1      1
 6     0      1
 7     1      1
 8     0      0
 9     0      0
10     0      0
11     1      1
12     1      1
13     1      1
14     0      1
15     1      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I'm sorry for not defining the problem well, I hope that the replacement only happens when less than three 0 are sandwiched between 1. (e.g., c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0) will be c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0). or even c(0,0,1,NA, NA,1,0,1,0,0) will be c(0,0,1,NA, NA,1,1,1,0,0). Is there any suggestion for this condition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update following reformulation of the question: This tidyverse approach simply makes use of `case_when()`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(dt, inputX = case_when(input == 0 &
                              lag(input) == 1 &
                              lead(input) == 1 ~ 1,
                              input == 0 &
                              lag(input) == 0 &
                              lag(input, n = 2) == 1 &
                              lead(input) == 1 ~ 1,
                              T ~ input))

#    input inputX
# 1      0      0
# 2      0      0
# 3      1      1
# 4      1      1
# 5      1      1
# 6      0      1
# 7      1      1
# 8      0      0
# 9      0      0
# 10     0      0
# 11     1      1
# 12     1      1
# 13     1      1
# 14     0      1
# 15     1      1
```

Previous solution: Having understood the requirements like Tarjae did, a tidyverse option could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(x = cumsum(input)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(y = +(n() %in% 2:3)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  transmute(input = input,
            inputX = if_else(y == 1, 1, input))

# # A tibble: 15 x 2
#    input inputX
#    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1      0      1
# 2      0      1
# 3      1      1
# 4      1      1
# 5      1      1
# 6      0      1
# 7      1      1
# 8      0      0
# 9      0      0
# 10     0      0
# 11     1      1
# 12     1      1
# 13     1      1
# 14     0      1
# 15     1      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I’m sorry that I didn’t define the problem well, which caused everyone's confusion. I have updated my question that I will hope to ignore the 0s that are in raw 1 and 2. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @yi-tingFang: You are very welcome. I have updated my post.